# How to scrape dynamic website - using python scrapy?

Tags: javascript, python, dom, web-scraping, scrapy

I can scrape static website using scrapy however, this other website that I'm trying to scrape has 2 sections in its HTML namely; "head" and "body onload". And the information that I need is in the body onload part. I believe that content is loaded after html is requested and thus the website is dynamic. Is this doable using scrapy? What additional tools do I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [scrapy_splash](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), it's a rendering service for scrapy, that will allow you to crawl javascript based web sites.

You can also create your own downloader middleware and use **Selenium** with **PhantomJS** ([example](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scrapy-users/vRZEP1vyJg8)). The downside of this technic is that you lose the concurrency provided by scrapy.

Anyway, I think **splash** is the best way to do this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can I use proxies with scrapy_splash?

Comment: Sure, it's in the documentation, [here](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-request-object.html?#request-set-proxy)